# WooCommerce product export/import with variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, export, product

I am looking for plugin with import/export WooCommerce products with variable, for this I am using "woocommerce import/export products" plugin
it works but puts each one as an individual product Like 
iphone 6 with 500 minutes
iphone6 with 1000 minutes
as 2 separate products
but in reality it's 1 product with variables.

What should I do? 
Is there any plugin who do it?

Answer (score 1):

Variable products can be imported using the plugin [Product Import Export Plugin For WooCommerce](https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/).